# Sharepoint Keywordquery search returns less results than default sharepoint search

Tags: keywordquery, sharepoint-search

I have a requirement in which I want to get the search results programmatically. For this I am using KeyWordQuery to search programmatically. But here I am getting less results that default SharePoint search, it is omitting some records from the results.

Here is the code I am using

```
    SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
    KeywordQuery objkeywordquery = new KeywordQuery(site);
    objkeywordquery.QueryText = strQuery;
    objkeywordquery.SelectProperties.Add("Title");
    objkeywordquery.SelectProperties.Add("Path");

    objkeywordquery.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default;
    objkeywordquery.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
    objkeywordquery.RowLimit = 5000
    ResultTableCollection queryResults = objkeywordquery.Execute();
    ResultTable queryResultsTable = queryResults[ResultType.RelevantResults];

    DataTable queryDataTable = new DataTable();

    queryDataTable.Load(queryResultsTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

f I get 100 results in sharepoint search reults page, with the same querytext I get 96-97 results. Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `TrimDuplicates = false;` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.query.trimduplicates.aspx

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
KeywordQuery objkeywordquery = new KeywordQuery(site);
objkeywordquery.QueryText = strQuery;
objkeywordquery.SelectProperties.Add("Title");
objkeywordquery.SelectProperties.Add("Path");

objkeywordquery.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default;
objkeywordquery.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
objkeyworkquery.TrimDuplicates = false;
objkeywordquery.RowLimit = 5000
ResultTableCollection queryResults = objkeywordquery.Execute();
ResultTable queryResultsTable = queryResults[ResultType.RelevantResults];

DataTable queryDataTable = new DataTable();

queryDataTable.Load(queryResultsTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

Comment: Super, happy to help:)