# SharePoint Keyword Query search returns fewer results than default SharePoint search for specific Sub Site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, search-results, kql

I am trying to retrieve the search result from specific Sub Site using KQL in SharePoint 2010.but I am getting only one result with custom code. However the OOTB Search result returns 5 results for the same Query Text.

I have already checked [This Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90261/sharepoint-keywordquery-search-returns-less-results-than-default-sharepoint-sear)

Here is my Code .

```
using (SPSite scSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)) 
        {
          using (SPWeb webRoot = scSite.OpenWeb()) 
          {
             scSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
             webRoot.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
             SearchServiceApplicationProxy proxy = (SearchServiceApplicationProxy)SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy(SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site));
             KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(proxy);
             keywordQuery.ResultsProvider = Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchProvider.Default;
             keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
             keywordQuery.EnableStemming = true;
             keywordQuery.QueryText = query;
             keywordQuery.HiddenConstraints = "This Site: " + SPContext.Current.Web.Name + "";
             keywordQuery.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
             ResultTableCollection searchResultTables = keywordQuery.Execute();
             ResultTable searchResult = searchResultTables[ResultType.RelevantResults];
             var resultsDataTable = new DataTable {TableName = "Results"};
             resultsDataTable.Load(searchResult, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
           }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `Path` managed property rather than your hidden constraint?

Comment: Thanks @MatthewMcDermott, It worked with Path Managed Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using the **Path** managed property in the QueryText of KQL.

i.e., query = (Search Term) ((Path:a))